# Is it possible to destructure a property out of the object and assign it to a property on the constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring

I'm using typescript and want to destructure properties out of an object. the problem is that I need to assign it to a property on the constructor of the class:

```
var someData = [{title: 'some title', desc: 'some desc'}];
var [{title}] = someData; // 'some title';
```

I want something more like:

```
var [{title :as this.title$}] = someData;
```

Is this possible in any shape or form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but you need to remove the declarator (`var`) since you are destructuring into something that already exists. Also, the `as` is invalid syntax. Remove it.

```
[{title: this.title$}] = someData;
```

A complete example:

```
const someData = [
  { title: 'Destructuring' }
];

class A {
  title$: string;
  constructor() {
    [{ title: this.title$ }] = someData;
  }
}
```

[TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=var%20someData%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20title%3A%20'Destructuring'%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%24%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%7B%20title%3A%20this.title%24%20%7D%5D%20%3D%20someData%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

[Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=var%20someData%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20title%3A%20'Destructuring'%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20var%20%20%20%5B%7B%20title%3A%20this.title%20%7D%5D%20%3D%20someData%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

**Via a Stack Snippet**

```js
const someData = [{
  title: 'Destructuring'
}];

class A {
  constructor() {
    [{title: this.title$}] = someData;
  }
}

console.log(new A());
```